# R language, how to sum values by group skipping the same numbers (nested in another a group)?

Tags: r, nested, sum, mean

I want to add a new column, calculating the average bonus for each company per employee, for example, the expected output for company A is (18+8+2)/3, and fill the value to each row of company A. Then same logic for company B, C, D. BTW, the rows with duplicated values cannot be dropped. At first, I was thinking to calculate the sum of the mean of bonus, but the code didn't work. Then I was thinking to add a loop skipping the same values, but it didn't work either. Anyone has some thoughts? I appreciate that a lot!

[image]

Comment: Please copy and paste the text from your data into the question. An image can't be used to work with by those that might otherwise write an answer.

Comment: 1. Your image shows an empty grid. 2. An image is a terrible way for you to provide data.  None of us wants to type it all in.  Instead,  please use `dput` to make a text form of your data that we can cut and paste.

Comment: Do you need `aggregate(Bonus ~ CompanyID, unique(df1[c('CompanyID', 'Bonus')]), mean)`

Comment: @thelatemail, apparently you don't have a package that understands the `.NORM` file format https://xkcd.com/2116/

Comment: @r2evans :-) I _loved_ that day's XKCD.

Comment: Thank you for your comments and answers. This is the first time for me to post a question here. I didn't know how to use dput, but I'll figure it out next time.

Answer (score 0):

Lacking readable input, I made up some

```
set.seed(30258)
df <- tibble(COMPANY.ID = sample(LETTERS[1:4], 20, replace = TRUE),
             EMP.ID = sample(1:5, 20, replace = TRUE),
             BONUS = sample(2:20, 20, replace = TRUE)) %>% 
  arrange(COMPANY.ID, EMP.ID, BONUS)

# A tibble: 20 x 3
   COMPANY.ID EMP.ID BONUS
   <chr>       <int> <int>
 1 A               1     3
 2 A               2    13
 3 A               2    16
 4 B               1    10
 5 B               1    18
 6 B               2    20
 7 B               3     3
 8 B               4    20
 9 B               5     7
10 B               5    10
11 B               5    10
12 C               2     4
13 C               3     4
14 C               3    16
15 C               5     4
16 C               5    13
17 D               1     8
18 D               1     9
19 D               3     8
20 D               4    12
```

A formula for the company's avg bonus - if an employee receives multiple bonuses from the same company, they are additive.

```
avgCoBonus <- df %>% 
  group_by(COMPANY.ID) %>% 
  summarise(AVG.BONUS = round(sum(BONUS) / length(unique(EMP.ID)), 2)) 


# A tibble: 4 x 2
  COMPANY.ID AVG.BONUS
  <chr>          <dbl>
1 A               16  
2 B               17.6
3 C               13.7
4 D               12.3
```

I *think* that's what you had in mind.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, David! But what I want is not a summary, I want to create a new column and fill the results to the column. Anyway, I've figured it out. And I'd like to share my answer here for anyone who has the the same question. Library(dplyr) df1<-df%<%group_by(CompanyID)%<%mutate(PhysicianTreatDur = mean(tapply(Bonus,EmployeeID,mean)))